# Como usar un metodo de un fragment desde otro fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Buenas tengo el siguiente dilema, tengo dos fragments en un activity y ahí un fragment que completa tareas de una lista y en el otro aparecen las que estan completadas. Como tiene una base de datos detras, para cargar la lista de las tareas completadas tengo un metodo en el fragment 2, y necesito que desde el fragment 1 cuando termine una tarea llamar a ese metodo y recargarlo.

Dejo el codigo del fragment 1

```
public class PageFragment1 extends Fragment {

FloatingActionButton fab;
ListView listErrands;
View vista;
int groupId;
int admin;
String ipServer;
String emailUser;
static ArrayList<String> g = null;
static ArrayList<Integer> idErrands = null;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_errandsnotfinish,container,false);
    fab = vista.findViewById(R.id.addErrandFab);
    listErrands = vista.findViewById(R.id.listErrands);
    groupId = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getInt("groupId", 0);
    ipServer = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("ipserver");
    emailUser = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("emailUser");
    admin = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("admin", 0);

    if(admin==0){
        fab.hide();
    }

    extractErrands(ipServer+"extractErrands.php?groupId="+groupId+"");

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getContext(), AddErrands.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("groupId", groupId);
            myIntent.putExtra("ipserver", ipServer);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    return vista;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    extractErrands(ipServer+"extractErrands.php?groupId="+groupId+"");
}

private void extractErrands(String url){

    //Create a json array request to obtain a array whit the data
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            g = new ArrayList<>();
            idErrands = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                try {

                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    g.add(jsonObject.getString("errandName"));
                    idErrands.add(jsonObject.getInt("errandId"));


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            showGroups();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Parece que no hay actividades", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueueq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueueq.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

private void finishErrands(String url, final int idPosition){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            g.remove(idPosition);
            idErrands.remove(idPosition);
            showGroups();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<>();
            parametros.put("groupId", Integer.toString(groupId));
            parametros.put("errandId", Integer.toString(idErrands.get(idPosition)));
            parametros.put("emailUser", emailUser);
            return parametros;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showGroups(){

    final ArrayAdapter adaptet = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.listview_groupsmain, R.id.groupName, g);
    listErrands.setAdapter(adaptet);
    listErrands.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alerDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
            alerDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.finisherrands).setMessage(R.string.aresure).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finishErrands(ipServer+"finishErrands.php", position);

                }
            }).setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).create().show();
            adaptet.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Como se puede ver cuando se pulsa en una tarea de la lista salta una alerta, si es positivo se llama a un método para terminar la tarea, pues justo despues de ese método me gustaria llamar al método del fragment 2

```
public class PageFragment2 extends Fragment {


ListView listErrands2;
View vista2;
int groupId;
String ipServer;

static ArrayList<String> g = null;
static ArrayList<String> nameUser = null;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    vista2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_errandsfinish,container,false);
    listErrands2 = vista2.findViewById(R.id.listErrands2);
    groupId = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getInt("groupId", 0);
    ipServer = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("ipserver");

    extractErrandsComplete(ipServer+"extractErrandsComplete.php?groupId="+groupId+"");
    return vista2;
}

public void extractErrandsComplete(String url){

    //Create a json array request to obtain a array whit the data
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            g = new ArrayList<>();
            nameUser = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                try {

                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    g.add(jsonObject.getString("errandName"));
                    nameUser.add(jsonObject.getString("username"));


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            showErrandsComplete();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No hay actividades completadas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueueq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueueq.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

public void showErrandsComplete(){
    final ArrayAdapter adaptet = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.listview_groupsmain, R.id.groupName, g);
    listErrands2.setAdapter(adaptet);
    listErrands2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.CompleteBy)+nameUser.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    extractErrandsComplete(ipServer+"extractErrandsComplete.php?groupId="+groupId+"");
}
```

}

El metodo a llamar seria el extractErrandsComplete, este sacaria todos los datos de la base de datos y los cargaria en un list view

Comment: Podrías mirar cómo comunicarte a través de la activity o incluso de callbacks pero lo ideal es que cambies el enfoque ya que tienes un problema de acoplamiento y eso provoca que la solución se complique... de hecho la web de androiddevelopers ya explican cómo resolver esto en su artículo: Cómo comunicar contenido con otros fragmentos shorturl.at/kvLR6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para comunicar dos fragments lo puedes hacer de dos maneras: una a traves de interfaces y otra a traves de un ViewModel.

Para explicarte la primera te pondré una estructura de ejemplo:

El MainActivity el cual contiene ambos fragments.

```
MainActivity implements MyInterface{

    FragmentA fa;
    FragmentB fb;

onCreate(){

    fa = new FragmentA(MainActivity.this);
    fb = new FragmentB();
}

//Metodo de la interface

void comunicarConFragmentB(String mensaje){
    fb.imprimirMensaje(mensaje);
}

}
```

El FragmentA, el cual contiene una instancia (como interfaz) de el Activity que lo contiene:

```
    FragmentA{

        MyInterface comm;

    //Constructor

    FragmentA(MyInterface comm){

        this.comm = comm;
    }


    //Metodo que realizara una accion (como escribir un mensaje)

    void enviarMensaje(){

        String mensaje = "Mensaje desde el Fragment A";
        comm.comunicarConFragmentB(mensaje);
    }

    }
```

El FragmentB, el cual imprimira el mensaje enviado desde el FragmentA:

```
FragmentB{

    TextView tv;

//Constructor

FragmentB(){

    //Inicializas el textView al activity del fragment correspondiente
    tv = (TextView) findviewById(R.id.mi_textView_dentro_del_XML)

}


//Metodo que mostrata el mensaje en el textview.

void imprimirMensaje(String mensaje){

    tv.setText(mensaje);
}

}
```

Como funciona?

Digamos que tienes tus dos fragments en el mismo Activity, por lo cual el Activity sabe de la existencia de los fragments que contiene y puede manipularlos debido a que tiene instancias de cada uno dentro de el (fa y fb).

El FragmentA tendra un boton o alguna vista que llame al metodo **enviarMensaje()** al ser presionado. Este metodo **enviarMensaje()** crea un String y se lo pasa al metodo **comunicarConFragmentB(String mensaje)** del Activity que lo contiene por medio de la interfaz **comm**.

De esta forma, ahora el Activity tiene el mensaje y se lo pasa al FragmentB utilizando su instancia y llamando el metodo **fb.imprimirMensaje(Mensaje)**.

Finalmente, el metodo **imprimirMensaje(String mensaje)** dentro de la clase FragmentB es llamado, recibe el mensaje que llega desde el Activity como parametro y lo utiliza para mostrarlo en el TextView mediante **tv.setText(mensaje)**.

Esto lo puedes aplicar en tu codigo, en resumen; un fragmentA llama a un metodo del Activity que lo contiene por medio de una interfaz, y este Activity llama al metodo del fragmentB (lo cual es posible ya que el Activity tiene instancia de ambos fragments) y por ultimo, el fragmentB ejecuta el metodo invocado desde el Activity.

Otra forma es utilizando ViewModels, la cual te recomiendo utilizar, en resumen tu puedes hacer que varios Activities o Fragments tengan acceso a esta clase ViewModel, de tal forma que estan atentos a los cambios dentro del ViewModel.

Por ejemplo, el FragmentA tiene un metodo que cambia los datos de este ViewModel y el FragmentB esta a la escucha de los cambios realizados dentro del mismo ViewModel. Cada vez que el FragmentA realice un cambio (como cambiar un String), el FragmentB sera notificado y recibira ese cambio (String) dentro de un metodo donde tu podras manipular ese cambio (actualizar un textView, realizar un intent, etc).

Te dejo la informacion de AndroidDevelopers a cerca del ViewModel:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel